# How many teams have forced a game 7 after being down 3-1 in the series?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

I know 9 teams in NBA history have come back to win a series after being down 3-1 in the playoffs, but how many managed to take it to 7, regardless of whether they won the series or not?

Answer (score 2):

> ...how many managed to take it to 7, regardless of whether they won the series or not?

This has happened 31 times, courtesy mostly of [Ps3FifaCfc95 of Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/nba/comments/4lmm1y/game_7_results_after_a_31_deficit_was_overturned/). This can be verified using [Basketball Reference](http://www.basketball-reference.com/) or any respectable NBA source.

A 3-1 deficit has been overcome 11 times.

- [2016 Cavaliers Warriors](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/2016-nba-finals-cavaliers-vs-warriors.html) 4th away yes
- [2016 Warriors Thunder](http://www.basketball-reference.com/playoffs/2016-nba-western-conference-finals-thunder-vs-warriors.html) 3rd home yes

[image: 3-1 deficit NBA playoff results]

<sub>Note: "The first team is the one that came from 3-1 down, then there's the round, whether the recovering team were home or away, and whether they pulled off the comeback."</sub>